# association queries in feathers js

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, feathersjs

How do we create or add the sample paramter below to be a valida query params. Ive tried something below but it is error . does someone has an idea ? thanks.

#URL

```
http://localhost:3030/peopltable?$or[0][addedBy.person.name][$like]=HELLO&targetId=865
```

#what i tried

```
if (query ) {
    query = {
      targetId: query.targetId,
      $or[0][addedBy.person.name][$like] = "Hello"
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The same information from the URL should be called like:

```
if (query ) {
  query = {
    targetId: query.targetId,
    $or: [ { 'addedBy.person.name': { $like: "Hello" } } ]
  };
}
```